# How to get data after loop using promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise, scrape

I am working on an async problem. I'm making a web scraper and after I scrape the web, I need to put the data in my MongoDB database after putting it in. I need to send it into the frontend, but since I have a loop the elements I can't put the `res.json()` inside, as it'll gave an error (you can only send once after `res.json())`.

I'm stuck here. I've used promises before, but this is confusing.

```
router.get('/scrape', (req, res) => {
  request('http://www.nytimes.com', function test(error, response, html) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    // An empty array to save the data that we'll scrape
    const results = [];

    $('h2.story-heading, p.summary').each(function(i, element) {
      const link = $(element)
        .children()
        .attr('href');
      const title = $(element)
        .children()
        .text();
      const summary = $(element)
        .children()
        .text();

      const data = {
        title: title,
        link: link,
        summary: summary,
      };

      articles
        .create(data)
        .then((resp) => results.push(resp))
        // .then((resp) => Promise.resolve(results)) //
        // .then((jsonDta ) => res.json(jsonData)) // error you can only give response once.
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });
    console.log(results); // empty array
    res.json(results)// empty 
  });
});
```

My plan is:

- to scrape a site (loop the elements)
- then save into MongoDB (push the data into an array)
- then after the loop pass it to the frontend.

I need to put the query method `create...` inside the loop because I need each data to have an id.

Comment: where should I put my promise in this situation?  that's my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to accumulate results directly, you can map the elements contained in `$('h2.story-heading, p.summary')` to an array of promises, then aggregate with `Promise.all()`. The results you want will be delivered by `Promise.all(...).then(...)`.

```
router.get('/scrape', (req, res) => {
    request('http://www.nytimes.com', function test(error, response, html) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const promises = $('h2.story-heading, p.summary')
        .get() // as in jQuery, .get() unwraps Cheerio and returns Array
        .map(function(element) { // this is Array.prototype.map()
            return articles.create({
                'title': $(element).children().text(),
                'link': $(element).children().attr('href'),
                'summary': $(element).children().text()
            })
            .catch(err => { // catch so any one failure doesn't scupper the whole scrape.
                return {}; // on failure of articles.create(), inject some kind of default object (or string or whatever).
            });
        });
        // At this point, you have an array of promises, which need to be aggregated with Promise.all().
        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(results => { // Promise.all() should accept whatever promises are returned by articles.create().
            console.log(results);
            res.json(results);
        });
    });
});
```

If you want any single failure to scupper the whole scrape, then omit the `catch()` and add `catch()` to the `Promise.all().then()` chain.

Notes:

1. For `.get()` (and most other methods), the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get) is better than the [Cheerio documentation](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#get-i-) (but be careful because Cheerio is a lean version of jQuery).
2. At no point do you need `new Promise()`. All the promises you need are returned by `articles.create()`.

Comment: this works sir. I tried this approach but without `get()` it returns me a bunch of objects. and i was using each. it was so annoying.

Comment: @aRtoo: are you able to accept this answer? While it is not mandatory, it rewards the poster for their help, and is nice to do. There is documentation on how to accept answers if you are not familiar with how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use .map function to return all promises to Promise.all and then return the results.

```
      request('http://www.nytimes.com', function test(error, response, html) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var summary = $('h2.story-heading, p.summary')
        Promise.all(summary.map((i, element) =>{
            const data = {
              title: $(element).children().text(),
              link: $(element).children().attr('href'),
              summary: $(element).children().text(),
            };

           return articles
            .create(data)

        }).get())
        .then((result)=>{
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
        });
    })
```

Comment: thank you sir. ill try this. i tried forEach but gives me an error because cheerio has only built in each loop? i think. this might give me error as well.

Comment: @artoo cheerio do contain `.map()`, you can check :)

Comment: hey man. still doesnt work. i wonder this not about promise anymore

Comment: hello sir. yes im getting undefined but its ok now. some of the given solution works. thank you very much.

Comment: yes, I see, we have to use, .get(), after map(). which i missed. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#map-functionindex-element-

Comment: In general, you can write `$cheerioCollection.map(fn).get()` or `$cheerioCollection.get().map(fn)`. The advantage of the latter is that you don't need to remember the silly jQuery/cheerio order of arguments in the mapper function, `(i, element)`. By first converting to Array, it's `(element, i)` or more typically just `(element)`. I came across some edge case once where I didn't have the choice of which order to map/get but I can't recall the details.

Comment: i didnt that cheerio can be integrate with jQuery thats awesome. If i do this question would have never asked be i was using a forEach and didnt work because doesnt return a value like map

Comment: "integrate with" is not really the correct concept. jQuery is designed for client-side (browser) use. Cheerio is a jQuery derivative designed for server-side (node.js) use.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work (code not tested)

```
router.get('/scrape', (req, res) => {
  request('http://www.nytimes.com', function test(error, response, html) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    // An empty array to save the data that we'll scrape
    const results = [];

    $('h2.story-heading, p.summary').each(function(i, element) {
      const link = $(element)
        .children()
        .attr('href');
      const title = $(element)
        .children()
        .text();
      const summary = $(element)
        .children()
        .text();

      const data = {
        title: title,
        link: link,
        summary: summary,
      };

      const articleCreate = articles.create(data); 
      results.push(articleCreate);

    });

    console.log(results); // this is array of promise functions.

    Promise.all(results).then(allResults => {
      res.json(allResults)
    });

    // or you could use array.reduce for sequantial resolve instead of Promise.all
  });
});
```

Comment: this one works too but I don't know which one would i use. im just gonna test both on top. thank you sir.

Comment: thank you for the time to answer this question sir. appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, but `results` is an array of Promises, not results.